# how Postgres works internally

Tags: postgresql

I would like to learn how postgres works i.e how queries are handled internally,the read and write performance ? I don know where to start,help me with refrences

Comment: Just wrote an answer then found that this is largely a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/8005314/398670

Comment: sorry i din get appropriate answer for my search,so i posted it here.

Answer (score 7):

Bruce Momjian has an update of his old but useful presentation here:

http://momjian.us/main/writings/pgsql/internalpics.pdf

and there's [Tom Lane's classic "tour of PostgreSQL internals"](http://www.postgresql.org/files/developer/tour.pdf) as mentioned by Neil, and the [back-end flowchart](http://www.postgresql.org/developer/backend/) that illustrates the high level overview of the execution path.

Then take a look at the further resources here:

- http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Developer_and_Contributor_Resources
- http://www.postgresql.org/developer/

After reading the useful links from Neil and those mentioned above, your next port of call is:

https://github.com/postgres/postgres

i.e. the best reference is the source code. The PostgreSQL sources have some pretty detailed comments on data structures and functions, but you'll still land up wanting to attach a debugger and step through the code to see what it's doing sometimes. Use the tools provided, like the `pprint` function, to examine the state of the server.

Comment: I also back looking at the source code - the source for the timesta people field gives details about inadequacies in the implementation, rationale for date range limits and is can be quite funny in places! https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/master/src/include/datatype/timestamp.h

Answer (score 2):

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/internals.html

http://www.postgresql.org/files/developer/tour.pdf

http://momjian.us/main/presentations/internals.html

pardon my brevity, going to the pub

Comment: So you're either in New Zealand, or you start drinking early? (West Australian here).